# Expand child div in a container keeping the center same - CSS

Tags: html, css

Following is my HTML/CSS code which is working fine the only thing I am unable to make is that keeping center of child div fixed while increasing the size of the child div inside a container. Let me know how could I achieve this effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container {
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #CECECE;
        margin: auto;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .rect {
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        left: 150px;
        top: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        transition: width 2s, height 2s, border 2s;
    }
    .rect:hover {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zdvcm1mp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3 `transform` property and `scale` element on hover instead of changing `width` and `height`.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.rect {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 2s, border 2s;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.rect:hover {
  border-color: green;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed that using `scale` also increases width of border to 2 times, how can I make this to keep the same border width

Comment: @Nesh In that case you can change `top` and `left` position as suggested by Pranesh because `scale` will change all characteristics of an element.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.. You need to change the `top` and `left` also

https://jsfiddle.net/pranesh_ravi/zdvcm1mp/1/